# Tips on writing a vim function to set printerheader

Tags: vim

I know i can use `:set printerheader=%-%This\ is\ a\ file` to set a string as a printerheader.
My goal is to make a function that can work like this `:Title This is a file`

So far I attempted it like this

````
command! -nargs=+ Title call s:setTitle(<f-args>)
function! s:setTitle(...)
        let command = ":set printheader=%-%"+string(a:000)
        execute command
endfunction```
````

Comment: String concatenation is with `.`, not +

Comment: @D.BenKnoble ohw thanks at least now i get why the funtion is not just plain overkill but also that it wouldn't work anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use options as variables by prefixing them as ampersand: `set foo=bar` is equivalent to `let &foo="bar"`
- You don't need to escape spaces in normal strings
- When `-nargs=1`, the (single) argument can contain spaces

So:

```
command! -nargs=1 Title let &printheader="%-%<args>"
```